Graph Request on email messages fails with "ErrorItemPropertyRequestFailed"
Recently faced a issue in Graph API while requesting details of outlook email messages with error message 'ErrorItemPropertyRequestedFailed' which is said to occur if a property that may exist, but couldn't be retrieved (reference)
I selected all available props of a email message with query
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$select=*"


To know the prop on which the request fails, I broke down the query by selecting specific props and found that uniqueBody is the one that couldn't be retrieved in graph request. while excluding this from the selected query it doesn't throw any error and including it in query does.

I need UniqeBody content for some use case and I cannot skip it in the request. I guess, the large uniqueBody content might be the reason that makes the retrieval process fail.
Is there anything that I could make like adding parameters to request headers that throttles this case (heavy Uniquebody content) or anything that could help me retrieving those details/just skip the message that face this error. It becomes difficult to get the other message details as no delta or next link is obtained in response while facing this error.
Thanks in advance.
